# NetworkManager static routes not applied

Tags: network-manager

The interface has VLAN enabled. on default vlan (management lan, 10.0.0.1/24 physical if "enp0s31f6") I set

```
ipv4.routes: { ip = 192.168.0.1/32, nh = 10.0.0.1 }; { ip = 192.168.1.1/32, nh = 10.0.0.1 }
```

This traffic is allowed by 10.0.0.1.

route shows

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway.mynet   0.0.0.0         UG    400    0        0 Private
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     400    0        0 Private
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

When I add those entries manually using

```
sudo route add 192.168.0.1 gw 10.0.0.1
sudo route add 192.168.1.1 gw 10.0.0.1
```

route shows

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway.heimnet 0.0.0.0         UG    400    0        0 Private
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     400    0        0 Private
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.1     10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.1.1     10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

NetworkManager does not apply those static routes.

- They show up correctly in nmcli
- They show up correctly in nmtui (I prefer to use this)
- They show up correctly in ElementaryOS network settings

Where is my mistake?

Or is this a bug? I found reports online but they were closed with "WONT FIX" and they're old.

Thanks for help

Comment: You mention ElementaryOS. Are you using Elementary and is this problem in Elementary?

Comment: Are you aware that NetworkManager is about connection profiles, and that there is a fundamental difference between a connection profile and the actual interface/device? In other words, did you make sure to activate the profile? Check `nmcli device` and `nmcli connection`. And, if you modify a profile that is currently active, the changes only take effect after reactivating the profile with `nmcli connection up`.

Answer (score 0):

`nmcli connection up`

Thanks to thallers answer it works. That was missing. Didn't know that I had to do this. I just changed the entries in nmtui.